# Script not found in TFS Build Deploy Test

Tags: testing, tfs, automation

We have a pre-deployment script in our build that works and runs correctly when built and sent to a specific build controller and agent.

However, in the interest of streamlining, we've set up several Lab Environments and a build-test-deploy flow so that whenever a developer pushes a new build, it automatically builds the test methods and sends them to an environment for testing.

That part all works great and lovely and wonderful.  However:  The aforementioned script does not work in the build-deploy-test flow.  It's got the exact same path as a machine-specific build, but every time we run the build we get

> The system cannot find the file specified
>    Exception Message: Team Foundation Server could not complete the deployment task for machine 'TestController1', script '"#/80908/drop/AutomatedTests/AutomatedTests.Desktop/ExternalLibs/GetEi.ps1"'

Here's the process parameters for the machine-specific build that works
[image]

And here's the process parameters for the build-deploy-test that does not find the script (And yes, I've tried without quotes and without $(BuildLocation))
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe that the Test controller and Agents support the "store drop on the server". In order to use the build-deploy-test DevOps cycle you will need to:

1. Change to using a UNC drop location that is accessible from the Test Servers.
2. Use Release Management to do the deployment instead. It supports the server drops.

I would recommend using #2 as i have had great success with this approach.

Comment: We ended up having everything go to a drop location instead of dropping on the build server, solved a lot of other troubles besides this one.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the actual drop path was different from the other build template.  Using Lab Settings put everything under $(BuildLocation) as a root, so the ExternalLib folder path was just $(BuildLocation)\ExternalLib\Getei.ps1

If anybody else is having this issue I would recommend navigating to the drop path (in my case, \\TestController1) and checking to see where the script is actually being put relative to the rest of the build.